# Django get derived form CHOICES in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I have a Django form:

```
BAR_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'Cheers'),
    ('2', 'The Blue Oyster'),
    ...
)

class ProjectInfoForm(forms.Form):
    foo = forms.ChoiceField(
        CHOICES = BAR_CHOICES,
    )
    ...
```

of course when I save this data to a model the values are stored as integers in the db. Now, when I grab these values from the saved data they are integers. What is the best approach for getting the choice strings they are associated with. Should I import the BAR_CHOICES into the template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django provides a way to directly fetch the related string. Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

**Update:**

Example:

```
BAR_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'Cheers'),
    ('2', 'The Blue Oyster'),
    ...
)

class Project(models.Model):
   foo = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=BAR_CHOICES)
   ...
```

In the template you could simply do `{{project.get_foo_display}}`

Comment: isn't this for a model, not a form. And this isn't a modelform.

Comment: @DarwinTech: What exactly are you sending to the template. Can you show us the view code?

Comment: `foo` is a field in another model, called project. So I pass a project instance to the template and want to do `{{ project.foo }}` but get the human readable `BAR_CHOICES` string.

Comment: @DarwinTech: Updated the answer take a look

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render the choices in a template, you can iterate over `form.field.choices`.

If you want the string representation of a selected value in the template, you're going to have to write something in your view or form that can get you that information.

You could emulate `get_FOO_display` in your form..

```
def get_foo_display(self):
    return dict(BAR_CHOICES)[self.foo]
```

Comment: Can I then use this method directly in my template?

Comment: Of course. You just can't pass it arguments (which it doesn't take).